# Getting error while trying to create entry in Remedy AR System Server

Tags: java, remedy

I'm trying to create an entry in AR server but getting below error:

> ERROR (303): Form does not exist on server; HPD:Help Desk

Please help me out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happen when field z1D_RelationAction is missing on HPD:Help Desk form.

If you're using v8.1, the following steps help are known to help:

Instead of waiting for SLM SP1 please install /upgrade in below sequence :

1. 8.1 SP1 AR , Atrium , AI , ITSM.
2. 8.1 GA hotfix for SLM. And Contact Support.
3. SRM 8.1 SP1